# Integration by substitution to trigonometric functions

Tags: integration, trigonometry

Consider the integral 
$$
  \int \sin(ax+b)\cos(ax+b) \;\mathrm{d}x
$$

Can I put substitution for $\sin(ax+b)$? Or Should I give substitution to $(ax+b)$?

Comment: Try one. If it does not work, try the other one.

Comment: Alternatively just remember that $\sin(\theta) \cos(\theta)=\frac12\sin(2\theta)$.

Comment: try $u = ax + b$

Comment: If you want to avoid dealing with any negative signs in finding $du$, the substitution $u=\sin(ax+b)$ would be best, as $du=a\cos(ax+b) \, dx$, which as no negative sign that one must have to deal with. Of course, $u=\cos(ax+b)$ works too, though that would give a negative sign in $du=-a\sin(ax+b) \, dx$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $u = \cos (ax+b)$ or $\sin (ax+b)$. Either one should work.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Use [Werner Formula,](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html) $$2\sin A\cos B=\sin(A+B)+\sin(A-B)$$ in case the  integrand contains product of sine(s) or cosine(s)